# Complicated string split with two special character using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been using Javascript for quite sometime now but this problem really caught my attention

I created a program that splits players from a string into individual names.

For example
 "Sadio Mane (Liverpool), Diao Balde Keita (Monaco), Ismaila Sarr (Rennes)"

to

```
my_array = [Sadio Mane (Liverpool),Diao Balde Keita(Monaco),Ismaila Sarr (Rennes)];
```

I created a basic function that splits the names and gives me an array from a database which goes like this

```
 var my_array = [];
        var club = [];
        var names = [];

        function splitData(data) {
            var spl = data.split(",");
            my_array.push(spl);

        }
```

but then this string came along

"Fakhreddine Ben Youssef (Al Ittifaq, Saudi Arabia), Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri (Rennes, France)"

When i try to split this type of string it output the following

```
    my_array = [Fakhreddine Ben Youssef, (Al Ittifaq, Saudi Arabia), Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri , (Rennes, France)];

//which outputs

my_array[0]='Fakhreddine Ben Youssef';
my_array[1]='(Al Ittifaq';
my_array[2]='Saudi Arabia)';
my_array[3]='Saber Khalifa (Club Africain)';
my_array[4]='Wahbi Khazri' ;
my_array[5]='(Rennes';
my_array[6]='France)';
```

I think the problem is quite visible, It is splitting the comma in the brackets as well, if it would have been just this string I would have done it manually but there are more than 30 strings in similar fashion.

Comment: Split by `),` instead of `,`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu very close but look: `Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri ,` , some parts don't have `),`

Comment: the example you gave does contain `),` though? Splitting by `),` and adding an `)` character to each split item should work fine.

Comment: looks like maybe a use-case for regex. split on commas, but ignore commas that occur inside a pair of parens

Comment: This sounds like a good case for using something other than a comma as a delimiter, or indeed not storing multiple data fields as a single string in the first place: you could ignore commas inside parens, but it seems inevitable that eventually you'll have data that includes a comma outside the parens too.

Comment: @worc I believe regex could do the workd here but I don't have that much experience with regex

Answer (score 1):

You can define the regular expression with its own constant syntax:

```
var reg = /[^\s,]([^\,(\)]+)(\s)*\([^\(\)]+\)/g;
```

```js
var s = "Fakhreddine Ben Youssef (Al Ittifaq, Saudi Arabia), Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri (Rennes, France)";
var reg = /[^\s,]([^\,(\)]+)(\s)*\([^\(\)]+\)/g;
console.log(s.match(reg));
```

See the **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GMfMdA/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is some non-jQuery dependent code:

```
function advsplit(input, separator) {
var tmp = '';
var output = [];
var bracketCount = 0;
for (var index in input) {
    var value = input[index];
    if (value == '(') bracketCount++;
    if (value == ')') bracketCount--;
    if (value == separator && bracketCount == 0) {
        output.push(tmp);
        tmp = '';
    } else tmp += value;
}
output.push(op);
return output;
}
```

To split your string you should use: `advsplit('Fakhreddine Ben Youssef (Al Ittifaq, Saudi Arabia), Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri (Rennes, France)',',')`

```js
    function advsplit(input, separator) {
    var tmp = '';
    var output = [];
    var bracketCount = 0;
    for (var index in input) {
        var value = input[index];
        if (value == '(') bracketCount++;
        if (value == ')') bracketCount--;
        if (value == separator && bracketCount == 0) {
            output.push(tmp);
            tmp = '';
        } else tmp += value;
    }
    output.push(tmp);
    return output;
    }
    
console.log(advsplit('Fakhreddine Ben Youssef (Al Ittifaq, Saudi Arabia), Saber Khalifa (Club Africain), Wahbi Khazri (Rennes, France)',','))
```

Hope I helped!